# The script will not save the data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pulling my hair out about this script below. No mater what I do it will not save the data sent to it. I have set the script of many different ways and also tested it like I show below.

I have set the part that sends it to the script like this $pid = 6 $emailmsg = 1 etc.... and it worked. This is what is not making any sense to me. I have used this same script but with different var at least a dozen times in this program with no problem.

This is what the data looks like that I am sending to the script

```
print_r($_POST);

[emailmsg] => 1 [emailrt] => 2 [pid] => 6 [$emrtid] => 48 [$emmsid] => 46
```

This is one of the script that will not send the data to the database

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE options SET pid = ?,emailmsg = ? WHERE id = ?");
echo $stmt->execute(array($_POST['pid'],$_POST['emailmsg'],$_POST['emmsid']));


$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE options SET pid = ?, emailrt = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['pid'],$_POST['emailrt'],$_POST['emrtid']));
```

I also tried it like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE options SET 
         pid = ?,
         emailmsg = ? 
         WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('1', $_POST['pid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('2', $_POST['emailmsg'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('3', $_POST['emmsid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "UPDATE options SET 
    pid = ?,
    emailrt = ? 
    WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('1', $_POST['pid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('2', $_POST['emailrt'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('3', $_POST['emrtid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You need to be checking for errors.  The error message will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The man page says that the first parameter of bindValue is either a named placeholder from your prepared statement, or a 1-indexed position of the parameter. You're passing it a string, because you're using single quotes around the number. I don't know if it's causing the issue, but it's probably worth changing - it should be `bindValue(1, $_POST....)`

Comment: Andy Lester there are no errors otherwise I would be using them

Answer (score 1):

If you literally copied your `print_r` output to your question, the problem is that your `WHERE` condition is never met so no row is ever updated.

This:

```
echo $stmt->execute(array($_POST['pid'],$_POST['emailmsg'],$_POST['emmsid']));
```

should be:

```
echo $stmt->execute(array($_POST['pid'],$_POST['emailmsg'],$_POST['$emmsid']));
//                                                                 ^ that's what it looks like in your print_r
```

The same applies to `$_POST['emrtid']` in your second query: `$_POST['$emrtid']`.

Comment: I don't understand your answer at all. The print_r stuff was just to show what is being past to the script it is not part of the script

Comment: @user3326386 Look closely: `$_POST['emrtid']` is not the same as `$_POST['$emrtid']`. You are using a non-existent variable in your query so you will never find any rows to update.

Comment: Where in my code do you see $_POST['$emrtid']  code is below                 $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE options SET pid = ?,emailmsg = ? WHERE id = ?");
echo $stmt->execute(array($_POST['pid'],$_POST['emailmsg'],$_POST['emmsid']));


$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE options SET pid = ?, emailrt = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['pid'],$_POST['emailrt'],$_POST['emrtid']));

Comment: @user3326386 Read my answer again and spot the difference between the first line of code (wrong) and the second one (should be right). Although the comment below the second line kind-of gives it away...

Comment: I see it now it was in the in the input fields                         <input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?=$pid; ?>">                                   
                <input name="$emrtid" type="hidden" value="<?=$emrtid; ?>"> 
                <input name="$emmsid" type="hidden" value="<?=$emmsid; ?>"> I did not see that at all

Comment: @user3326386 Yes, your field is called `$emrtid` and not `emrtid` so you can change the name or add a dollar sign like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try like using named parameter:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE options SET pid = :pid, emailrt = :emailrt WHERE id = :emrtid");
$stmt->execute(array('pid'=>$_POST['pid'],
                     'emailrt'=>$_POST['emailrt'],
                     'emrtid'=>$_POST['emrtid']
));
```